# Maven Multi Module build

Tags: maven

Our project has a requirement where we want to build only modules which got changed and remaining should be referred from maven local repository or remote repository. Is there any way to do this?

Ideal solution would be if maven can detect any changes in modules from SCM like SVN and build only that and remaining pick from repsoitory

We want to do this because we have many modules and it takes lot of time to compile thus will save lot of time for us.

Comment: Why would you only want to build certain bits? That's not how maven is intended to be used.

Comment: First the question: What do you define as `takes lot of time` and about how many modules are we talking about? Are you using parallel build options? How many tests are you running and how long take those tests to run?

Comment: Idea is why to rebuild something which is not changed. Even if we build it's the same artifact so just a thought why not reuse what is already there in repository. Coming to number of modules it's 60. As of now don't have many tests but team is planning to add more